# username alert not working properly (popup condition)

Tags: android, flutter, authentication

when I am on the "avatar" page I save the username with "save" if the username is already taken an error popup is displayed to warn the user. but if the name is not used and respects the conditions then the data is saved and I can press the "save" button several times as long as I stay on the page, everything is valid there is no problem, on the other hand when I leave the page, and that I do not modify anything and that I press on "save" the popup of error of the user name appears. Why

I can provide you with the entire code of the application if it can help you (ask me, even if I don't see the interest that the rest may have because the problem is located on this page). Below is the code for the avatar page:

```
type here
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;

import 'package:LoginFly/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:LoginFly/views/sigin.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_advanced_drawer/flutter_advanced_drawer.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:LoginFly/views/avatar.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


Future<void> setLoggedIn() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', true);
}

Future<void> setLoggedOut() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', false);
}


// Enregistrer l'URL de l'image
void saveImageUrl(String imageUrl) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('imageUrl', imageUrl);
}

// Récupérer l'URL de l'image
Future<String?> getImageUrl() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString('imageUrl');
}




const String defaultImageUrl =
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginfly-95e0e.appspot.com/o/avatar.png?alt=media&token=1e95ef19-b452-4f76-a8f5-3a7d5406acd7&_gl=1*znzar2*_ga*NDMwMjY1ODk5LjE2ODU3MzI0NzI.*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY4NjQwMjA1MS45LjEuMTY4NjQwMjk4NC4wLjAuMA..";


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}



class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late String imageUrl;




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ChatRooms(imageUrl: imageUrl, name: '',),
    );
  }
}



class ChatRooms extends StatefulWidget {
  late final String imageUrl;
  final String name;

  ChatRooms({required this.imageUrl, required this.name});

  @override
  _ChatRoomsState createState() => _ChatRoomsState();

}

class _ChatRoomsState extends State<ChatRooms> {
  TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final picker = ImagePicker();// Ajoutez cette ligne pour déclarer et initialiser la variable usernameController
  String imageUrl = '';
  User? currentUser;
  late TextEditingController nameController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    _loadImageUrlFromFirebase();
    _loadUserName();
    nameController = TextEditingController(text: widget.name);

  }


  Future<void> _loadUserName() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String savedName = prefs.getString('${currentUser!.uid}_userName') ?? '';
    setState(() {
      nameController.text = savedName;
    });
  }

  void _handleLogoutPressed() {
    _onLogoutPressed(context);

  }

  Future<void> _loadImageUrlFromFirebase() async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        imageUrl = user.photoURL ?? defaultImageUrl;
      });
    }
  }

  void updateImageUrl(String newImageUrl) {
    setState(() {
      imageUrl = newImageUrl;
    });
  }



  void _handleAvatarPressed() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AvatarPage(
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        username: usernameController.text,
      )),
    ).then((newImageUrl) {
      if (newImageUrl != null) {
        updateImageUrl(newImageUrl);
      }
    });
  }





  final _advancedDrawerController = AdvancedDrawerController();
  bool isDrawerOpen = false;
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  bool isLoading = false;
  AuthMethods authMethods = AuthMethods();
  String? _errorMessage;


  var _isObscured;
  List<IconData> _icons = [
    Icons.home,
    Icons.account_circle_rounded,
    Icons.favorite,
    Icons.settings,
  ];

  List<String> _titles = [
    'Home',
    'Profile',
    'Favorites',
    'Settings',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AdvancedDrawer(
        backdrop: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: [Colors.deepOrange, Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2)],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        controller: _advancedDrawerController,
        animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
        animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        animateChildDecoration: true,
        rtlOpening: false,
        childDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
      drawer: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: 240,
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 150,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 55.0,
                      bottom: 55.0,
                    ),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: _handleAvatarPressed,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: imageUrl.isEmpty || imageUrl == null
                                    ? NetworkImage(defaultImageUrl)
                                    : NetworkImage(imageUrl),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            right: 0,
                            bottom: 0,
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),

                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // Add your logic here
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),


                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: Text('Home'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
                  title: Text('Profile'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                  title: Text('Favorites'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                  title: Text('Settings'),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 16.0,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Terms of Service | Privacy Policy',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      color: Colors.white30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60.0),
            child: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                  bottom: Radius.circular(20),
                ),
                color: Colors.grey, // Modifier la couleur de fond ici
              ),
              child: AppBar(
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                flexibleSpace: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                      bottom: Radius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.blueGrey, // Modifier la couleur de fond ici
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                title: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.white70.withOpacity(0.8),
                            blurRadius: 10,
                          ),
                        ],
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                      ),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        child: BackdropFilter(
                          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: _handleMenuButtonPressed,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/logo.png',
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Text(
                      'LoginFly',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                actions: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: _handleLogoutPressed,
                    // Appeler la méthode _handleLogoutPressed lors du clic sur la flèche de déconnexion
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.exit_to_app_rounded,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 24.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),

          body: WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
                if (details.primaryVelocity! > 700) {
                  _advancedDrawerController.showDrawer();
                } else if (details.primaryVelocity! < -700) {
                  _advancedDrawerController.hideDrawer();
                }
              },

              onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                if (details.delta.dx > 700) {
                  _advancedDrawerController.showDrawer();
                } else if (details.delta.dx < -700) {
                  _advancedDrawerController.hideDrawer();
                }
              },
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
              child: _getBodyWidget(_currentIndex),
            ),
          ),

            bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: ClipRRect(

                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                child: Container(
                  child: BottomNavigationBar(
                    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
                    onTap: (index) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentIndex = index;
                      });
                    },
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
                    unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
                    selectedFontSize: 14,
                    unselectedFontSize: 14,
                    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                    items: _icons
                        .asMap()
                        .map(
                          (index, icon) =>
                          MapEntry(
                            index,
                            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                              icon: Icon(icon),
                              label: _titles[index],
                            ),
                          ),
                    )
                        .values
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
        ),
    );
  }

          void _onLogoutPressed([BuildContext? context]) {
    showDialog(
      context: context ?? this.context, // Utilisez `this.context` comme valeur par défaut si `context` est nul
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
        title: Text('Confirmation'),
        content: Text(
          "Voulez-vous vraiment vous déconnecter ?",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            child: Text(
              'Non',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              authMethods.signOut();
              setLoggedOut(); // Appel de la fonction pour définir l'état de connexion sur false
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SingIn()),
              );
            },
            child: Text(
              'Oui',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Colors.white,
                // Autres propriétés de style que vous souhaitez appliquer
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget _getBodyWidget(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Contenu de l\'écran Home',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      case 1:
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Contenu de l\'écran Profile',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      case 2:
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Contenu de l\'écran Favorites',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      case 3:
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Contenu de l\'écran Settings',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      default:
        return Container();
    }
  }

  void _handleMenuButtonPressed() {
    if (isDrawerOpen) {
      _advancedDrawerController.hideDrawer();
    } else {
      _advancedDrawerController.showDrawer();
    }
  }


  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    if (isDrawerOpen) {
      _advancedDrawerController.hideDrawer();
      return Future.value(false);
    }

    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
        title: Text('Confirmation'),
        content: Text(
          "Voulez-vous vraiment vous déconnecter ?",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Colors.black,
            // Autres propriétés de style que vous souhaitez appliquer
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            child: Text(
              'Non',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Colors.white,
                // Autres propriétés de style que vous souhaitez appliquer
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
              SystemNavigator.pop(); // Ferme l'application
            },
            child: Text(
              'Oui',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Colors.white,
                // Autres propriétés de style que vous souhaitez appliquer
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ).then((value) => value ?? false);
  }
}
```

I am a beginner in this field and therefore I do not know much I would be very grateful if someone could take the time to look into the problem and accompany me so that I can understand how to solve it.